# Plague of Hails

Tags: theology, moshe-rabbeinu, egypt

[Shemoth 9:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.9.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0)-"So **Moses held out his rod toward the sky**, and Hashem sent thunder and hail, and fire streamed down to the ground, as Hashem rained down hail upon the land of Egypt."

Shemoth 9:33 - "Leaving Pharaoh, Moses went outside the city and **spread out his hands to Hashem**: the thunder and the hail ceased, and no rain came pouring down upon the earth."

Just a little confusion, what does the scripture want to specify when saying **"towards the Sky"** and when saying **"towards Hashem"**? What is the difference? To which direction did Moses spread His Hands - when spreading his hands towards Hashem?

Comment: As a general comment: Take a look at _all_ the plagues, and the splitting of the Yam Suf, and maybe the war with Amalek, and see how use of the staff/hands is described in each case. It's hard/maybe misleading to answer a very specific question on a bigger topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Moses performed the miracles of the plagues, he would extend the staff toward whatever would be affected, in this case the sky.

Moses spreading his hands to G-d does not necessarily mean a direction, it means an action of prayer, intended as part of his prayer to G-d.

Answer (score 1):

The primary contrast between the two is the concept of judgement and the concept of kindness.

Judgement is, in general, associated with the staff *of Moshe*. Like is emphasized in the Torah that he received the Ten Commandments *from the aspect of Judgement* (מפי הגבורה). *See Rashi to Numbers 16:3*

The reason for this is because the *Staff*, which is similar to a rod, scepter or reed (קו, מטה, שבט, קנה), and also like the cord in 2 Samuel 8:2 (חבל), are all tools for measuring (למודד מדד).

This underlines a general principle that G-d's judgement in the Torah is measured and restricted, meaning not unlimited, like the expression *measure for measure* (מדה כנגד מדה). G-d's judgement in regard to His creations is finite, like them, in contrast to the possibility His judgement being infinite like G-d, the Creator.

But Moshe also served in the place of and was equated with Aharon, his older brother. Aharon was from the side of kindness (חסד). And the corresponding action is the action performed by Aharon as Kohen Gadol of lifting his hands with fingers spread when blessing the people.

This idea of fingers spread and outstretched emphasizes the quality of kindness that G-d manifests within His creation. That His kindness exceeds His quality of judgement like is emphasized in the second of the ten commandments (Exodus 20:4-5), which says:

> You shall have no other gods besides Me.
> You shall not make for yourself a sculptured image, or any likeness of what is in the heavens above, or on the earth below, or in the waters under the earth.
> You shall not bow down to them or serve them. For I, your G-d, am an impassioned G-d, ***visiting the guilt*** of the parents upon the children, ***upon the third and upon the fourth generations*** *of those who reject Me*; but ***showing kindness*** ***to the thousandth generation*** *of those who love Me and keep My commandments*.

So to, Moshe performs this action when making a prayer to elicit kindness and curtail the plague.